# does not go inside fetch assoc loop

Tags: php, mysql

hello guys im trying to retrieve data from database 
i debugged everthing and it works normally 
my problem is the website does not go inside the second loop 
because when i try to print the counter and any of the sums it gives me 0
he is a part of my code where the problem happen:

```
<?php
      error_reporting(0);
        require 'db/connect.php';


       $results= $db->query("SELECT * FROM instructors");
        $counter=0;
          while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){

            $id=$row['id'];
            $query="SELECT * FROM Instructors LEFT OUTER JOIN ratings ON instructors.id=ratings.instructor Where instructors.id=".$id;
            $sum1=0;
            $sum2=0;
            $sum3=0;
            $count=0;


            if($result = $db->query($query)){
            while ($rowe = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
              $sum1+=$rowe['teaching_rating'];
              $sum2+=$rowe['marks_rating'];
              $sum3+=$rowe['help_rating'];
              $count++;
            }

             $result->free();
          }

            echo "<script> console.log('".$count."')</script>";
            $overall=(($sum1/$count)+($sum2/$count)+($sum3/$count))/3;
            $overall = floor($overall * 2) / 2;


}
          ?>
```

the previous way works on server fine but it has the mentioned problem above 
the following way completely works on localhost but when i upload it to the server it give php error

```
 while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){

       $id=$row['id'];
        $results1=$db->query("SELECT * FROM Instructors LEFT OUTER JOIN ratings ON instructors.id=ratings.instructor Where instructors.id=". $id);
        $sum1=0;
        $sum2=0;
        $sum3=0;
        $count=0;

        while ($rowe = $results1->fetch_assoc()){

          $sum1+=$rowe['teaching_rating'];
          $sum2+=$rowe['marks_rating'];
          $sum3+=$rowe['help_rating'];
          $count++;

        }
        $overall=(($sum1/$count)+($sum2/$count)+($sum3/$count))/3;
        $overall = floor($overall * 2) / 2;
```

so please help me fix one of them or both maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a problem in the outer query :
SELECT * FROM instructors instead of Instructors 
the weird thing that the local host works fine

but the server does not work
maybe because of the difference in version number

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this...

```
$sum1=0;
$sum2=0;
$sum3=0;
$count=0;

while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){

    $id=$row['id'];
    $query="SELECT * FROM Instructors LEFT OUTER JOIN ratings ON instructors.id=ratings.instructor Where instructors.id=".$id;

    $result = $db->query($query);

    while ($rowe = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $sum1+=$rowe['teaching_rating'];
        $sum2+=$rowe['marks_rating'];
        $sum3+=$rowe['help_rating'];
        $count++;
    }

    $result->free();
}
echo "<script> console.log('".$count."')</script>";
$overall=(($sum1/$count)+($sum2/$count)+($sum3/$count))/3;
$overall = floor($overall * 2) / 2;
//do something with $overall i guess
```

Comment: i need these variables to be reseted for every loop
there is coninuation to my code where i print the overall

anyways i tried your way and it does not change any thing 
thanks for trying to help

Comment: are you sure your inner query return records?